# PostgreSQL 9.3 operator <> doesn't give logical result

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have this code in a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER customernametrig
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON customers
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE  trig();
```

and the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trig()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
   if TG_OP='UPDATE' then
    RAISE NOTICE '%', new.customername;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', old.customername;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', new.customername<>old.customername;
    if new.customername<>old.customername then
        RAISE NOTICE 'hi';
    end if;
  end if;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

the `customername` column is of type citext.

When I run update command

```
Update customers set customername='Jack' where customerid=125;
```

field it prints:

```
NOTICE:  Jack
NOTICE:  jack
NOTICE:  f
```

But if I run `select 'jack'<>'Jack'` it gives me: `t`

So What I expect it to print is:

```
NOTICE:  Jack
NOTICE:  jack
NOTICE:  t
NOTICE:  hi
```

i don't understand this behavior. What is happening here?

Comment: You are probably confused about `NULL`s and probably should use `is distinct from` instead of `<>`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There are no nulls here. I'm asking about this specific comparsion Jack with jack : "For non-null inputs, IS DISTINCT FROM is the same as the <> operator."  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: out of curiocuty, add BEFORE UPDATE trigger and check if same?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Same behavior. This is no surprising. The values in old and new are correct the problem is with the compare.

Comment: @avi yeah... if you give table definition and one row - I can try reproducing this at my db - I'm just from vacation, so I'm a bit slow. and I dont see why 'a' <> 'A' would be false in trigger...

Comment: @avi again out of curiocity, is it so when you `update customers set customername='Vao' where customerid=125; ` ?.. and also check if indexes are not corrupted (if customernameis indexed of course), and also to exclude custom operators or other miracles check if it persists when you change `<>` to `!=`

Comment: @VaoTsun The table has 25 columns most of them are empty. I created a "slim" row for my checks and this happens in this row as well. basicly all I have there is the customerid and customername.  so you can create customerid integer , customername citext.

Comment: `citext` is case insesitive - so its expected result - I felt there's smth like that - so set to 'Vao' should RAISE `hi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html

> The citext module provides a case-insensitive character string type

...

> citext performs comparisons by converting each string to lower case
>   (as though lower were called) and then comparing the results normally.
>   Thus, for example, two strings are considered equal if lower would
>   produce identical results for them.

```
t=# select 'jack'<>'Jack';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

t=# select 'jack'::citext<>'Jack';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Omg! I would have never guessed this is the problem. Thanks. But i'm not sure I understand why `select 'jack'::citext<>'Jack'::citext` gives `false`.

Comment: if at least one compared (not importand if left or right) is of `citext`, it performs `lower` on both compared values